How many neighbourhoods are needed to cover the edge graph of a 6 dimensional hypercube
For a vertex in a graph, define its neighbourhood to be the set containing itself and all its neighbours (sometimes referred to as closed neighbourhood to distinguish from just the set of neighbours).  So for example, in the graph formed from the $1$-skeleton of the $6$-dimensional hypercube, every neighbourhood has cardinality $7$.  Say a set of neighbourhoods covers a graph, if its union contains all the vertices of the graph.
Question How many neighbourhoods are needed to cover the edge graph of the $6$-dimensional hypercube?
I am particularly interested in whether the number is above $12$.  So far I have managed to get $12$ neighbourhoods which cover all but two of the vertices, so the minimal number of neighbourhoods is at most $14$.  We get a crude lower bound by dividing $64$ by $7$ and rounding up to $10$.
Taking a greedy approach, it is possible to select $8$ disjoint neighbourhoods, which then cover $56$ of the vertices.  However, no pair of the remaining $8$ vertices belong to a common neighbourhood, so this approach ends up needing $16$ neighbourhoods, which we have already beaten.
We may depict a $6$ dimensional hypercube as a chessboard, where squares are adjacent precisely when they are $4$ squares apart horizontally (or vertically), $2$ squares apart horizontally (or vertically), but in the same horizontal half (resp. vertical half), or $1$ square apart horizontally (or vertically), but in the same horizontal quarter (resp. vertical quarter).
The green marks indicate the centers of $8$ disjoint neighbourhoods:


Is the "edge graph of the $6$-dimensional hypercube" something different from the ordinnary 6-dimensional hypercube graph?

@MishaLavrov No, the word edge may be unnecessary detail here.

@xxxxxxxxx I meant the graph whose vertices are vertices of the hypercube, and edges are edges of the hypercube.   As it seems to be causing confusion I will delete the word "edge".

A set of vertices $S$ in a graph $G$ is called a dominating set if every vertex not in $S$ has a neighbour in $S$. The size of a smallest dominating set is the so called domination number of a graph, usually denoted $\gamma(G)$. OEIS entry A000983 lists the domination numbers of the first few $n$-dimensional hypercubes $Q_n$. In particular, $\gamma(Q_6) = 12$.
Below is an example of a dominating set of $Q_6$ of size $12$, where each vertex is represented by a binary tuple of length $6$ in the natural way.
\begin{align*}
v_1 &= (0,0,0,0,0,1) \\
v_2 &= (0,0,0,1,1,0) \\
v_3 &= (0,0,1,0,1,1) \\
v_4 &= (0,1,0,0,1,1) \\
v_5 &= (0,1,1,0,0,0) \\
v_6 &= (0,1,1,1,0,1) \\
v_7 &= (1,0,0,0,1,0) \\
v_8 &= (1,0,0,1,1,1) \\
v_9 &= (1,0,1,1,0,0) \\
v_{10} &= (1,1,0,1,0,0) \\
v_{11} &= (1,1,1,0,0,1) \\
v_{12} &= (1,1,1,1,1,0) \\
\end{align*}
I got this list from formulating the problem as an integer linear program, as below, and plugging it into a solver. We have a binary variable $x_v$ for every vertex. $N[v]$ denotes the closed neighbourhood of $v$, i.e., $v$ together with its neighbours.
\begin{align}
&\min \sum_{v\in V(Q_6)}x_v\\
\text{s.t.} &\sum_{u\in N[v]}x_u\geq 1, \forall v\in V(Q_6)\\
&x_v\in \{0,1\}, \forall v\in V(Q_6).
\end{align}

Thanks very much.  I followed some of your links further and came across the solution $(000011, 000100, 001010, 011001, 011101, 011111, 100101, 101011, 101100, 110000, 110010, 110110).$  Out of interest, how did your algorithm work?

@tkf I just used a linear programming solver, see my edit.

That's neat - I have not used one of those.

Following links provided by the accepted answer lead to the solution below.  The diagram depicts a 5-dimensional cube.  Every red vertex is adjacent to both a green vertex and a purple vertex.  Thus if we double up to a depiction of the 6-dimensional cube, we get a dominating set by taking the green vertices from one side and the purple vertices of the other.

